# Getting the name of the tab under which a custom field is held

Tags: jira

Does anybody know of a Jira 4.2 API function that will allow me to return the tab under which a particular field is held in a screen? I need to be able to pull tab names and link them to fields for an external issue renderer that requires custom field IDs and tab names for logical layout. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is anyway to find that with the default 4.2 SOAP API. You could write your own SOAP method. Or maybe add the tab name to the field description and use getCustomFields perhaps?

Comment: As I suspected, I think I will have to do it manually. Thanks!